# Checking for occurance in a file is not working

Tags: php, html

I have a php script which checks for user information to see if the exam has been taken already.

The Pastebin for the script: **http://pastebin.com/z8fsrakw**

The code which actually does the processing begins here:

```
$type = "Clinical";
$writeSuccess = "";
$path_to_names_file = 'storenamecli.txt';
$theemails = file($path_to_names_file);

if (strtolower($theemail) == "nurse") {
        $theemail .= rand();
}

if($fname <> "" && $lname <> "" && $theemail <> "" && $empid <> "" && $doh <> "" && (!empty($ydept) && $ydept <> "#")) {
        if(file_exists($path_to_names_file) && in_array(strtolower($theemail), $theemails)) {
```

It was working, If an user takes the exam and passes it and goes back tries to take it again it won't let them. But I am not sure what happened, it allows the same user to take multiple exam without stopping the user.

I know the script might not be as effecient, but I would like to know where is the issue that is preventing from the "prevent taking the exam twice" work properly.

Comment: You appear to be using `$theemails` then `$theemail`. There is no code showing where `$theemail` comes from. Did you leave it out?

Comment: read the docs for [PHP's `file` function](http://php.net/file) - it returns an array, not a string. Try [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) instead.

Comment: `$theemail = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['theEmail'])));` is taken from the form.

Comment: IMO: Using a DB would be much easier to manage for something like this.

Comment: I agree but this is a temporary solution until I have the DB up and running.

Comment: @SiKni8 I understand. Just giving *"my 2 cents"* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- No problem and I am with you in your 2 cents lol, hence I upvoted your comment, because I know it would be much easier :)

Comment: @SiKni8 Thanks and am glad you found [your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19693699/1415724) cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `file` function is creating array values with trailing newlines. Remove them:

```
$theemails = array_map('chop', file($path_to_names_file));
```

I.e.:

```
<?php
   $name = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "");
   file_put_contents($name, "1\n2");
   var_dump(file($name), array_map('chop', file($name)));
?>
```

Outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(2) "1\n"
  [1] =>
  string(1) "2"
}
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "1"
  [1] =>
  string(1) "2"
}
```